# I have a bit a of code that has one command that runs fine on the terminal but fails when running from a script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

The script is shown fails to run at the last command.

The command runs fine when ran individually in the terminal. I've tried putting the !... part in a parameter, moving it around, using various brackets and line breakers and even using full paths. I'm not interested in alternative solutions - I'm interested in why doesn't this solution work in a script specifically.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    mkdir alllogs
    for i in $(locate *.log); do cp $i alllogs/; done
    tar -zcvf alllogs/logs.gz alllogs/*
    rm -v alllogs/!('logs.gz')
```

The script collects various logs from the Linux system and compresses them into a single file, after which it erases the copies of the logs leaving the compressed file alone. However, the command to delete the copies fails when ran through the script but works fine from the terminal.
The Error that is given out is:

```
    ./x.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    ./x.sh: line 7: `rm -v alllogs/!('logs.gz')'
```

Comment: Looks like globbing issues. Take a look over https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78376/in-linux-how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-pattern-txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That form of [pattern matching](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) is not enabled by default. You need to explicitly set `extglob`.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score 0):

What vintnes said, or replace

```
$(locate *.log)
```

with

```
`locate *.log`
```